# State management best practises using firebase and redux in react native

Tags: firebase, react-native, redux, redux-toolkit, react-native-firebase

My app needs to implement Firebase authentication and get data from the realtime database for each user (structured as /users/{uid}/{data}). However I have not come across good information on how to access the data for each screen of my app. The options that I can't decide between are:

- use the on listener from react-native-firebase in the root of the app to push the updated state to redux each time a user property updates
- push a property value to both firebase and redux in each component when it needs to update a value
- use redux only for state management and push data to firebase real time database when needed (for data redundency and iot devices)

I have avoided using firebase by itself to manage state as fetching each property for a component is rather slow, consumes a lot of bandwidth and I want the app to work for users that do not have an internet connection.

I have looked at other libraries like react-redux-firebase for state management but they seem outdated and I'm wondering what are the current best solutions for state management for an online focused app that doesn't rely exclusively on firebase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We typically want a single source of truth. Implementation described in option 2 seems to not follow this paradigm. That being said your intuition/ reasoning of not using firebase for state management seems correct as updating firebase for each update of UI component can be slow.

Maybe use redux/ state variables to manage UI/ component state within the app and only update firebase for data that you want to persist across app sessions.

Lastly, how you fetch updated data from firebase depends on how your app uses data. For example, if you need to fetch data for only 1 user then you can fetch it in root component and populate your redux there. If you need to fetch data for multiple users then it iss better to fetch it in component where you need it based on user id prop.

This answer might seem a bit generic but hope it helps. Please share more implementation details and I will try to provide a more detailed answer.

Comment: My only concern is the bandwidth usage and performance issues if listening for the entire time the user is using the app.

Comment: HTTP API requests typically don't use a lot of bandwidth/ network data and do not cause any performance issues either, even if you have the app listening for updates for constantly.
For example, in our IoT based app we listen for updates over MQTT constantly while the app is in use and also make HTTP requests a few times every minute. Just remember to cancel the subscription/ listeners when your app is backgrounded.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend creating a different folder and file for redux/contextAPi and firebase config file.

Use redux for all app-wide state changes as a default. When it comes to fetching data from firebase, use async await for data that is needed right now and isn't available in local storage. But if the data is available in both local storage as well as firebase, then async await firebase but fetch local storage using redux/contextApi in the meantime to update state change sooner. The firebase should be the only source of truth, but if the data is also available in redux and its correct, then there is no harm in fetching from there also.